# Fastest way to copy c++ vector<float> to Obj-C Float32 array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, floating-point, objective-c++

I'm making a function call in my Obj-C++ which returns a C++ float vector:

```
vector<float> mixedFrames = song.getMixedFrames();
```

These frames are for audio playback and CoreAudio expects them inside a `Float32` array which was defined like this:

```
Float32 *buffer = (Float32 *)ioData->mBuffers[channel].mData;
```

My question is which is the fastest way to copy `mixedFrames` to `buffer`. Should I just loop through `mixedFrames` and copy every value to `buffer` or is there a faster way which would take less memory?

Comment: `std::copy` will be heavily optimised and do the right thing

Comment: Will that work with an Objective-C object such as Float32 though?

Comment: @Sled, `Float32` isn't an object type.  It's just a `typedef` to `float`.  Check out `CFBase.h` to see it.

Comment: Why copy at all? Why not just use `mixedFrames.data()`?

Comment: You mean do something like `buffer = mixedFrames.data()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory layouts are the same, so there may not be a need to copy at all; you can simply use `mixedFrames.data( )`.

If you actually need to make a copy for some reason, you can simply use `memcpy` or `std::copy`.

Comment: But `buffer` is a pointer so I have to copy, no? Or do you mean doing something like `buffer = mixedFrames.data()`?

Comment: It depends on what you are going to do with the data; if you just need a pointer to pass it to some routine, then you can simply use `mixedFrames.data()`; you don't need `buffer` at all.

Comment: Buffer is a function-argument (pointer) in this case so I'm not returning it. I can't use mixedFrames directly.